# Register User Validation

Tags: php, html, database

The code below allows the user to register to my website. they must enter a username, password, and an email. I have included my all PHP code for you have a better understanding, basically, it is just to validate what the user enters and if the user enters valid details it will be stored in the Database. I will include the code below which are currently not working. Thanks and also I am only new to PHP.

```
<?php

    include('classes/DB.php');

    //function to abstract information entered and then store it
    if (isset($_POST['createaccount'])) 
    {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];

            if (!DB::query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username)))  // Username Validation (Duplicate)
                {
                    if (strlen($username) >= 3 && strlen($username) <= 32)//Length of Username Validation
                     {
                            if (preg_match('/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/', $username)) // Username - Validation = Allow the Username to include a-z , A-Z , 0-9
                            {
                                    if (strlen($password) >= 6 && strlen($password) <= 60) //Length of Password Validation
                                    {

                                    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))  // Email Validation (Duplicate)
                                    {
                                            DB::query('INSERT INTO users VALUES (\'\', :username, :password, :email)', array(':username'=>$username, ':password'=>password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT), ':email'=>$email)); // Encrypts password 

                                            echo "Success!";
                                    } 

                                    else
                                    {
                                      echo 'Invalid email!'; //Error message  -  Email Duplicate
                                    }

                            }

                             else 
                             {
                               echo 'Invalid password!'; //Error message - Length of Password
                             }

                           } 

                            else
                            {
                              echo 'Invalid username1'; //Error message -  Username 
                            }

                    } 

                    else
                    {
                     echo 'Invalid username';  // Error message - Username
                    }

                 } 

            else 
            {
                    echo 'User already exists!'; //Error message - Duplicate Username
            }
    }

    ?>
```

I am having a problem with these lines of code as if I enter the same username into the website it still adds it into the database which it shouldn't.

```
if (!DB::query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username)))  // Username Validation (Duplicate)
```

Also when the user enters into the textbox it should be hashed

```
DB::query('INSERT INTO users VALUES (\'\', :username, :password, :email)', array(':username'=>$username, ':password'=>password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT), ':email'=>$email)); // Encrypts password
```

Comment: You have to use row count fir checking the username already exists or not.

Comment: and... make username in DB unique

Answer (score 0):

For checking if user exists already by his username, use this :

```
<?php
   $user = DB::query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username',
                    array(':username'=>$username));
   if(!empty($user->fetch()))
    {
      //Instruction 
    }
 ?>
```

Of course, the best way to ensure the no duplicating of username is to add unique constraint since your DBMS